# Should I check for keywords like 'SUCCESS' in action types?

Tags: javascript, redux, indexof

Can I do this in a reducer?

```
if(action.type.indexOf('SUCCESS') !== -1){
    return state.merge({
      [action.field]:action.data
    });
  }
```

My constant is defined like this: `${moduleName}/SUCCESS/${entity}`. Is this consistent with the basic principles of Redux?

Comment: don't see why not.  What is your concern?

Comment: I did not see this in other projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as you never use that particular combination for anything else. On balance, I would rather export that specific constant:

```
export const FLARGLE_SUCCESS_WORFLE = `${moduleName}/SUCCESS/${entity}`

// ...

case FLARGLE_SUCCESS_WORFLE:
  // ...
```

If only because it's easier to read in the reducer, and you don't have to run `indexOf` over and over.